# Angular Material mat-checkbox not showing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am currently trying to implement Angular Material Checkboxes in my side but it won't work for me for some reason. The box isn't showing up. Can someone look over my code and imports?

These are my current imports:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the code I try to create the box with:

```
<section class="example-section">
    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
  </section>
```

Comment: do you have any console error? or can you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks no issue, there should be some other issues in your project.
I have created a simple checkbox sample on stackblitz with less imports:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umypmc

TS:

```
import './polyfills';

import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import {CheckboxOverviewExample} from './app/checkbox-overview-example';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  declarations: [CheckboxOverviewExample],
  bootstrap: [CheckboxOverviewExample]
})
export class AppModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

HTML:

```
<section class="example-section">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
</section>
```

Comment: Made a new project and used your imports it still doesn't work for me for some reason

Comment: Have you checked the stackblitz i attached?

Comment: Yes I did and it helped very much, I realized that I had made a mistake while setting up the whole project. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Kyh Just to ask would you mind sharing what mistake have you made? My checkbox is also not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You must add

```
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';
```

into your *app.module.ts*, and *imports* that module in @NgModule as follows:

```
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material/checkbox';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Comment: It looks like OP has already done these things.